# Error when checking partial derivatives of slinear structured metamodel

Tags: openmdao

I am using the MetaModelStructuredComp Component to perform an interpolation in a 2D grid.

When checking the option to compute it with the 'slinear' method, the interpolation appears to work correctly, but when checking partial derivatives with a complex step, it returns a large error (order of 10^-1) for the derivatives with respect to the second dimension and second node (they belong to a grid point, but also the first node).

This does not happen when checking with all the other methods (cubic returning order of 10-15, and scipy_slinear with a finite difference check in the order of 10-10). The scipy_slinear check returns an analytical and numerical finite difference of that component which is almost identical to the one returned by the numerical finite difference of the slinear method (around -0.03338752, but note that the analytical returns -0.05107948)

I am not sure if its something I am missing, or if there is an error in the analytical partials for the slinear.

In my code, the first dimension is alpha with trained data of shape (12,), and second dimension mach (5,). I am checking with two outputs (C_D (12, 5) and C_L (12, 5), both having the same large error)

The LiftDragCoefficientsMetaModelPretrimmedGroup code is:

```
class LiftDragCoefficientsMetaModelPretrimmedGroup(om.Group):
def initialize(self):
    self.options.declare('num_nodes', types=int,
                         desc='Number of nodes to be evaluated in the RHS')
    self.options.declare('machs', default=np.arange(10),
                         desc='Vector of machs defining grid')
    self.options.declare('alphas', default=np.arange(10),
                         desc='Vector of alphas defining grid')
    self.options.declare('C_D_grid', default=np.zeros(10),
                         desc='Drag coefficients from grid')
    self.options.declare('C_L_grid', default=np.zeros(10),
                         desc='Lift coefficients from grid')
    self.options.declare('extrapolate', types=bool,
                         desc='Allow extrapolation if true',default=True)
    self.options.declare('interp_method', types=str,
                         desc='Interlopation Method', default='slinear')

def setup(self):
    comp=om.MetaModelStructuredComp(method=self.options['interp_method'],
                                    extrapolate=self.options['extrapolate'] ,
                                    vec_size=self.options['num_nodes'] )
    comp.add_output('C_L', self.options['C_L_grid'].mean(), self.options['C_L_grid'])
    comp.add_output('C_D', self.options['C_D_grid'].mean(), self.options['C_D_grid'])
    comp.add_input('alpha', self.options['alphas'].mean(), self.options['alphas'])
    comp.add_input('mach', self.options['machs'].mean(), self.options['machs'])

    self.add_subsystem('comp', comp, promotes=["*"])
    self.comp._no_check_partials = False  # override skipping of check_partials
```

The code routine used is:

```
model = om.Group()
model.add_subsystem('InterpSubsystem',
                    LiftDragCoefficientsMetaModelPretrimmedGroup(num_nodes=3,
                                                                 machs=rw.machs,
                                                                 alphas=rw.alphas*np.pi/180.0,
                                                                 C_L_grid=rw.c_Lt_grid,
                                                                 C_D_grid=rw.c_Dt_grid,
                                                                 interp_method='slinear',
                                                                 extrapolate=False))
p = om.Problem(model)
p.setup(force_alloc_complex=True)

p.set_val('InterpSubsystem.alpha', np.array([35 * np.pi / 180, 10 * np.pi / 180, 8.5 * np.pi / 180]))
p.set_val('InterpSubsystem.mach', np.array([5, 7 , 7.5]))
p.run_model()
print(p['InterpSubsystem.C_L'])
print(p['InterpSubsystem.C_L']-np.array([rw.c_Lt_grid[8,1],rw.c_Lt_grid[3,3],0]))
print(p['InterpSubsystem.C_D'])
print(p['InterpSubsystem.C_D']-np.array([rw.c_Dt_grid[8,1],rw.c_Dt_grid[3,3],0]))

cpd = p.check_partials(compact_print=False, method='cs')
assert_check_partials(cpd, atol=1.0E-7, rtol=1.0E-7)
```

The error code is the following:

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
  InterpSubsystem.comp: 'C_L' wrt 'alpha'
    Analytic Magnitude : 1.313053e+01
          Fd Magnitude : 1.313053e+01 (cs:None)
    Absolute Error (Jan - Jfd) : 8.881784e-16

    Relative Error (Jan - Jfd) / Jfd : 6.764226e-17

    Raw Analytic Derivative (Jfor)
[[7.45312355 0.         0.        ]
 [0.         8.300603   0.        ]
 [0.         0.         6.92543442]]

    Raw FD Derivative (Jfd)
[[7.45312355 0.         0.        ]
 [0.         8.300603   0.        ]
 [0.         0.         6.92543442]]

 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
  InterpSubsystem.comp: 'C_L' wrt 'mach'
    Analytic Magnitude : 1.331524e-01
          Fd Magnitude : 1.274173e-01 (cs:None)
    Absolute Error (Jan - Jfd) : 1.769196e-02 *

    Relative Error (Jan - Jfd) / Jfd : 1.388505e-01 *

    Raw Analytic Derivative (Jfor)
[[-0.11945724  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.         -0.05107948  0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.         -0.02916183]]

    Raw FD Derivative (Jfd)
[[-0.11945724  0.          0.        ]
 [ 0.         -0.03338752  0.        ]
 [ 0.          0.         -0.02916183]]


--------------------------------
Component: InterpSubsystem.comp
--------------------------------
< output > wrt < variable > | abs/rel | norm   | norm value          
--------------------------- | ------- | ------ | --------------------
C_L wrt mach                | abs     | fwd-fd | 0.017691955836769413
C_L wrt mach                | rel     | fwd-fd | 0.13885048495831204 
C_D wrt mach                | abs     | fwd-fd | 0.004933779456698817
C_D wrt mach                | rel     | fwd-fd | 0.05287403976054622
```

Comment: I reproduced this with some random data for the tables, so it might be a bug. We will take investigate further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what I think is happening here (and what I stumbled upon with my random table) is that 7.0 is one of the points on which your Mach data is defined. When you use the 'slinear' method, the derivatives are discontinuous at that point. It's just one of the disadvantages of the method.

The discrepancy in the check happens because the bracketing algorithm, which figures out which bin you are interpolating, chooses the "left" bin when you are on a grid point, but the finite difference or complex step chooses the "right" bin because the default check direction is "forward".

To alleviate future confusion, we're going to set the check direction to "backward" for the structured meta model component whenever the 'slinear' method is chosen.  The derivatives "matched" when I made this change. This change should make it into OpenMDAO 3.11.

Comment: Thank you for looking into it, I was wondering if something like that was going on. Maybe because of this sort of discontinuities is also less advisable to use linear interpolations for gradient based optimizations

Comment: the C1 discontinuity can sometimes be problematic in optimizations. The smoother interpolations have their own issues too though. In general I have not found the C1 discontinuity in the slinear approach to introduce too many problems. It certainly could if you ended up right on the data point for some reason though.